# Display user's name after login using session (php and sqlsrv)

Tags: php, sql-server, session, authentication

**session.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    if($_SESSION['valid_user']!=true){
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
    }
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$db_host = '(local)';
    $db_user = 'user';
    $db_pwd = 'pwd';
    $database = 'Demo';

    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
    if( !$conn )
    {
         echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_get_last_message(), true));
    }
?>
```

**homepage.php**

```
<?php   
require_once 'session.php'
require_once 'connection.php';
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE EmployeeId='$EmployeeId'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result); // ERROR
$EmployeeId = $row['EmployeeId'];
$UserName = $row['UserName'];

sqlsrv_close($conn);

echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['UserName'] . ' | ' . $_SESSION['EmployeeId'] //ERROR
?>
```

I would like to display the **name** (UserName) of the user after the user log into the site by using the session. But i can only display the  **employee id** (EmployeeId) as i've created the session from the login_action

**login_action.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'session.php'
require_once 'connection.php';
$EmployeeId = $_REQUEST['EmployeeId'];
$Password  = $_REQUEST['Password'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE EmployeeId='$EmployeeId' AND Password='$Password'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

if($num==1){
    header('Location: homepage.php');
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EmployeeId'] = $EmployeeId;
    die();}
else
    header('Location: login_error.php');
    die();

?>
```

Could you help me on how can i display the user's name as i got these errors :

```
Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in homepage.php line 22
```

AND

```
Notice: Undefined index: UserName in homepage.php line 33
```

I've searched everywhere and i can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: You never set $_SESSION['UserName'] that's why you get the undefined notice

Comment: Also, I can't see you have set a connection in your login_action.php

Comment: @michael Yes but i'm confused. At what page should i create the $_SESSION['UserName'] ? I mean it's not proper to create them in the login_action.php. Can you give me example how? i'm new to sqlsrv and php

Comment: @michael I have them in my login_action.php. Its just that i didn't paste them here. Btw, the login is successfull. The problem now is just it can't display the User's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution months ago. But decided to post to share with other readers who've been experiencing the same problem as i am.

**session.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if($_SESSION['valid_user']!=true){
header('Location: login.php');
die();
}
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$db_host = 'local';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = 'pwd';
$database = 'MyDB';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);
if( !$conn )
{
     echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_get_last_message(), true));
}
?>
```

**login_action.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'connection.php';

$EmployeeId = $_POST['EmployeeId'];
$Password  = $_POST['Password'];
$UserType = $_POST['UserType'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[LOGIN] WHERE EmployeeId='$EmployeeId' AND Password='$Password' AND UserType='$UserType'";
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql,$params , array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if($num==1){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EmployeeId'] = $EmployeeId;
    $_SESSION['UserType'] = $UserType;
    if($UserType == "USER")
    {
        header("Location: user.php");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($UserType == "SUPERIOR")
    {
        header("Location: superior.php");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($UserType == "ADMIN")
    {
        header("Location: admin.php");
        exit();
    }
    else 
    die("Not a Valid User Type.");

    }
    else
    //die(sqlsrv_errors());
    header('Location: login_error.php');
    exit();

?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $EpId = $_SESSION['EmployeeId'];

    $tsql = 
    "SELECT * 
    FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[USER]
    WHERE EmployeeId = '$EpId'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), array ("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $EId = $row['EmployeeId'];
        $uName = $row['UserName'];
    }

    echo 'Welcome $uName | $EpId';

    ?>
```